# MySQL FULLTEXT query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to query using mysql FULLTEXT, but unfortunately its returning empty results even the table contain those input keyword.

**Table: user_skills**:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------+
| id |                    skills                    |
+----+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Dance Performer,DJ,Entertainer,Event Planner |
|  2 | Animation,Camera Operator,Film Direction     |
|  3 | DJ                                           |
|  4 | Draftsman                                    |
|  5 | Makeup Artist                                |
|  6 | DJ,Music Producer                            |
+----+----------------------------------------------+
```

**Indexes:**

[image: Indexes for the abovr table]

**Query:**

```
SELECT id,skills 
FROM user_skills 
WHERE ( MATCH (skills) AGAINST ('+dj' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

Here once I run the above query none of the `DJ` rows are returning. In the table there are 3 rows with is having the value `dj`.

Comment: could be your term is tooo short

Answer (score 3):

Your search term is to short

as in mysql doc

> Some words are ignored in full-text searches:
>
> Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is three characters for
>   InnoDB search indexes, or four characters for MyISAM. You can control
>   the cutoff by setting a configuration option before creating the
>   index: innodb_ft_min_token_size configuration option for InnoDB search
>   indexes, or ft_min_word_len for MyISAM.
>
> .
>
> Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics:
>
> They do not use the 50% threshold.
>
> They do not automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance.
>   You can see this from the preceding query result: The row with the
>   highest relevance is the one that contains “MySQL” twice, but it is
>   listed last, not first.
>
> They can work even without a FULLTEXT index, although a search
>   executed in this fashion would be quite slow.
>
> The minimum and maximum word length full-text parameters apply.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   .. yes  ..(i know) the answer  was for a general pourpose ...anayway  .. answer  updated  removed the ref. to stopword .. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 3):

A full text index is the wrong approach for what you are trying to do.  But, your specific issue is the minimum word length, which is either 3 or 4 (by default), depending on the ending.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html), specifically [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length).

Once you reset the value, you will need to recreate the index.

I suspect you are trying to be clever.  You have probably heard the advice "don't store lists of things in delimited strings".  But you instead countered "ah, but I can use a full text index".  You *can*, although you will find that more complex queries do not optimize very well.

Just do it right.  Create the association table `user_skills` with one row per user and per skill that the user has.  You will find it easier to use in queries, to prevent duplicates, to optimize queries, and so on.